# Using tags to indicate what technologies are allowed

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed that people use tags of technologies/languages that are not present in the actual question:

- [remove border Color of others if one is onblur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585343/remove-border-color-of-others-if-one-is-onblur) -> [html5](/questions/tagged/html5), [css3](/questions/tagged/css3)
- [Browser compatibility issues with CSS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585333/browser-compatibility-issues-with-css3) -> [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), [css3](/questions/tagged/css3)
- [send newsletter with delayed_job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583329/send-newsletter-with-delayed-job) -> [ruby-on-rails-3](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-3), [ruby-on-rails-3.1](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-3.1)

(probably all these questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-3+ruby-on-rails and other question that uses similar tags with version numbers embedded)

I was tempted to remove these tags, as they are not relevant for the question and are used to attract attention (in a wrong way IMHO).

But then I was wondering whether they were added to indicate that these technologies/languages are available to answer the question...

My question/discussion is: *'Is it allowed/intended to (mis)use tags for these purposes, or should I remove them?'*

Personally, I still tend to remove them, as the answer might or might not use these tags and they are (still) misused. But please correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: I'd consider it a smell...and I'd also remove unnecessary tags.

Answer (score 1):

They should contain those tags if they expect answers in that technology, but it is important that they also include in the question that they want answers using a certain technology. Instead of removing the tags, you should, after clarifying with the asker, add to the question that all answers should use a certain technology, and maybe you should also inform the asker about putting in expectations for the technologies used in answers for future questions.

If after clarifying with the asker you find that the asker does not require answers to use a certain technology, yet the asker included a tag for that technology, then remove that tag and notify the asker about not using unnecessary tags.

I think this because answer requirements on technologies influence what the ideal answer's technology used will be, which influences the topic of the question, and tags indicate topics. Users who are good at a certain topic often use tags to find questions on that subject.

Answer (score -1):

Requirements should be *organic* to the question - tags are not a replacement for including all the relevant information in the question itself.

In these specific scenarios, having technology tags would help with finding/filtering such questions, especially on SO, so having the *correct* tags helps.

In all these questions, the tags are being used *instead of* rather than *in conjunction* with saying "I'd like to do this in FOO if possible.

*Version* tags are a bit contentious. In some cases they may make sense (python 2 and 3 have fairly distinct syntaxes) in some cases they may not. Use of meta + common sense needs to be used here. For example, does ruby on rails 3 and 3.1 have something that other versions do not which would be useful here?

I'd not *remove* the tags here, but *prompt* clarification requests, and moving this information into the main body would be a good start.